# "Process finished with exit code 0" but desired output is not shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python and have created this tiny class "myclass" which is inside a module called linear_regression_example.py. It prints out a regression summary and a density plot:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import sklearn.datasets as skld
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

class myclass:
    def __init__(self, result=1):
        self.result = result

    def myregression(self):
        y_X = skld.load_boston()
        y = y_X['target']
        X = y_X['data']
        n = y_X['feature_names']
        y = pd.DataFrame(y)
        X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=n)
        X = sm.add_constant(X)
        mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
        result = mod.fit()
        if self.result == 1:
            print(result.summary())
        pred = mod.predict(result.params)
        pred = pd.DataFrame(pred)
        errors = y - pred
        sns.distplot(errors)
        plt.show()
```

I also have another file, called test.py:

```
import linear_regression_example as lre

test = lre.myclass()
test.myregression()
```

Running test.py in pycharm results in the output "Process finished with exit code 0" but no summary or plot is shown. Maybe someone here knows where the problem lies.

Best regards

Dominik

Comment: I just tried this and it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linear_regression_example.py

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import sklearn.datasets as skld
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

class myclass:
    def __init__(self, result=1):
        self.result = result

    def myregression(self):
        y_X = skld.load_boston()
        y = y_X['target']
        X = y_X['data']
        n = y_X['feature_names']
        y = pd.DataFrame(y)
        X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=n)
        X = sm.add_constant(X)
        mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
        result = mod.fit()
        if self.result == 1:
            print(result.summary())
        pred = mod.predict(result.params)
        pred = pd.DataFrame(pred)
        errors = y - pred
        sns.distplot(errors)
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = myclass()
    test.myregression()
```

test.py

```
import linear_regression_example  as lre

test = lre.myclass()
test.myregression()
```

OUTPUT (from test.py)

[image: test.py]

Comment: But I have to confess that I do not fully understand the structure here. What would I have to to if I wanted to change the parameter "result" to 0 when calling myclass from test.py?